# Why indexOf() and contains() doesn't work as i intended in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, contains, indexof

```
// Objects for the bookstore I created

BookStore bookStore = new BookStore("Subu's Book Store","Perambur");
bookStore.addItem(new Item("Animal Farm",20));
bookStore.addItem(new Item("Animal Farm",20));
```

---

Output if I used the original working method:

```
Animal Farm has been bought
Animal Farm is already bought
```

Output for the method that doesn't work using contains()

```
Animal Farm has been bought
Animal Farm has been bought
```

Output for the method that doesn't work using indexof()

```
-1
Animal Farm has been bought
-1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
at com.company.subusproject.BookStore.searchItem(BookStore.java:41)
at com.company.subusproject.BookStore.addItem(BookStore.java:16)
at com.company.subusproject.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

---

This is the original method that works

```
public boolean searchItem(Item item) {
  for (int i = 0; i < this.myStocks.size(); i++) {
    Item foundItem = this.myStocks.get(i);
    if (foundItem.getName().equals((item.getName()))) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is the method I don't know why it doesn't work, how I intended this method to work is, if the variable **searchingItem** returns true then the method **searchItem** will return if not it returns false

```
public boolean searchItem(Item item) {
  // this method returns the boolean value true if found, if not returns false   
  boolean searchingItem = this.myStocks.contains(item);
  if(searchingItem){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is also doesn't work as I intended. The way I intended this method to work is, when i found the index position of the element i am looking for and then compare it with the elements that are available in the list **myStocks** and that isn't the case in this scenario as well.

```
public boolean searchItem(Item item) {
  // this method returns the index number of the founded element, if not returns -1
  int itemPosition = this.myStocks.indexOf(item); // this line always returns -1 in this scenario
  for(int i=0; i<this.myStocks.size(); i++){
    if(myStocks.get(itemPosition).getName().equals(myStocks.get(i).getName())){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Store class to create a any store class

```
public abstract class Store {
  private String name;
  private String address;
    
  public Store(String name, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }
    
  public abstract boolean addItem(Item item);
    
  public abstract boolean removeItem(Item item);
    
  public abstract boolean searchItem(Item item);        
}
```

Basic items class to add any kind of items

```
public class Item {
    
  private String name;
  private int price;
    
  public Item(String name, int price){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
    
  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
    
  public int getPrice(){
    return this.price;
  }  
}
```

Actual book store class where it has the methods to add and search

```
public class BookStore extends Store {
        
  private List<Item> myStocks;
        
  public BookStore(String name, String address) {
    super(name, address);
    this.myStocks = new ArrayList<>();
  }
        
  public boolean addItem(Item item) {
    if (!searchItem(item)) {
      this.myStocks.add(item);
      System.out.println(item.getName() + " has been bought");
      return true;
    } else {
      System.out.println(item.getName() + " is already bought");
      return false;
    }
  }
        
  public boolean searchItem(Item item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.myStocks.size(); i++) {
      Item foundItem = this.myStocks.get(i);                
      if(foundItem.getName().equals((this.myStocks.get(i).getName()))) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Clearly, I know the assumption I am making about how it should work is wrong and the problem is with those inbuild methods and how I wanted them to work but that isn't the case.

Comment: Please do not link textual output as images.

Comment: Please format your code and don't put code/text as images

Comment: `contains` and `indexOf` rely on either the `hashCode` or `equals` method of object. You haven't implemented either of them so it will never work as it will always return a different hashCode and false for equals.

Comment: You need to implement `equals`/`hashCode` on `Item` for `myStocks.contains(item)` to behave as expected, see https://medium.com/@sp00m/java-object-identity-or-how-to-override-equals-hashcode-and-compareto-400fd4547fe0.

Comment: You need to only show the code that is relevant

Comment: sorry i edited thoroughly to the best i can express

Comment: Tip: If the main purpose of the class is to communicate data transparently and immutably, use the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature in Java 16 and later, to benefit from the default implementations of `equals` & `hashCode`.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution:**

You have to implement [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) in `Item`, as [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) relies on `equals`.

If you do not override `equals` Java by default resorts to [reference equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251419/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-reference-equality-vs-object-equality-in-java).

From the documentation of `contains`:

> Returns `true` if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this list contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

**Rules for overriding `equals`:**

Partly taken from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts): Java SE defines a contract that `equals` must fulfill. The `equals` method must be:

- *reflexive*: an object must equal itself
- *symmetric*: `x.equals(y)` must return the same result as `y.equals(x)`
- *transitive*: if `x.equals(y)` and `y.equals(z)` then also `x.equals(z)`
- *consistent*: the value of `equals` should change only if a property that is contained in `equals` changes (no randomness allowed)

**Why also overriding `hashCode`?**

Also partly taken from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts). Java SE also defines a contract for the `hashCode` method. A thorough look at it shows how closely related `hashCode` and `equals` are. All three criteria in the contract of `hashCode` mention in some ways the `equals` method:

- *internal consistency*: the value of `hashCode` may only change if a property that is in `equals` changes
- *equals consistency*: objects that are equal to each other must return the same hash code
- *collisions*: unequal objects may have the same hash code (i.e., just because two objects have the same hash code does not mean that they are equal)

I suggest to utilize the IDE to auto-generate `equals` and `hashCode` and to only use `final` fields within both methods to determine their return value.

**Only if these rules are followed, we can expect data structures from the standard library (or any other data structure) to work correctly.**

Comment: You explain that `contains` relies on `equals.  Why does `hashCode` have to be implemented?

Comment: @Basya Because the documentation of `equals` demands that `hashCode` has to be implemented as well whenever `equals` is overriden. Methods are allowed to rely on this fact at any time. So even when `contains` might not use `hashCode` today, it might use it tomorrow. Just use your IDE to auto-generate both methods.

Comment: Thank you @Zabuzard.  I think the answer would be clearer with that explained...

Comment: This is wholly new information for me, I never heard of overriding equals and hashcode, could you explain why it is and how to implement it? How it is contains() is linked to equals and hashcode, i used contains many times on primitive data and it worked fine but i never usd it on objects. I did some google on this concept and it all are a little overwhelming for me?

Comment: I just expanded my answer. I hope it helps. If so, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: @mockingbird - you are correct that this would be a good addition to the answer.  To implement the functions though -- most IDEs will generate them automatically for you I believe, and then you can just check them to confirm that they do what you want (compare the fields necessary to determine equality, ignore any fields which are not relevant such as temporary state information or some such).  The basic idea is to tell the 'contains' function how to know whether two objects are equal.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger - I can't accept; I'm not the OP, but the edit got an upvote from me.  I've learned something new today.

Comment: @mockingbird Did my answer help you in understanding the underlying problem?

Comment: Yes, it pushed me in the right way, your answer and the subsequent links and references that follow, and actually, when I override the equals() method in my item class, both indexOf() and contains() method works without overriding hashcode() method,  what my doubts really are, the contracts of equals(), I can understand the theory as I learned them in algebra, but I can't make sense of them in the actual implementation of the contract such as reflexiv, symmetric , transitive and mainly about consistent with equals

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement `equals()` method in you `Item` class, `contains()` or `indexOf()` internally use `equals()` method. also Since it comes in contract  you have to implement `hascode()` method this will make sue there is no breaking contract.

If you don't implement hashcode it will take memory location based on JVM implementation which will always return different int for equal object as well, it will fail while you use the Item object as key in hashmap, also its performance while hashing Collections much depends on Hascode implementations (long subject so not getting in details).

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Comment: Not only `equals`, also `hashCode`.

Comment: as long as you not using Object in Hashing key it wont matter if you are implementing hascode or not, but yes it would still be good idea to do so in order to complete the contract.